# Having loop problems with Remove() using binary heaps & comparators -Java

Tags: java, loops, comparator

we have a binary heap of 10 items. I am trying to get the "Remove" function to work using comparators.
i am running into an infinite loop situation and am not sure exactly why. Any thing will help. Thanks.

```
public E remove() {        
    int current = 1;
    int lastValue = size();

    E element = get(lastValue);
    set(1,element);

    remove(lastValue);

    int left = current * 2;
    int right = current * 2 +1;

    E leftElement= get(left);
    E rightElement= get(right);

    int value1 = comp.compare(element, leftElement);
    int value2 = comp.compare(element, rightElement);

    while(value1 == 1 || value2 == 1){
        int value3 = comp.compare(leftElement, rightElement);
        if (value3 == 1){
            //left > right
            set(current, rightElement);
            set(right, element);
            current = right;

        }
        else{
            set(current, leftElement);
            set(left, element);
            current= left;            
        }

        int left2 = current * 2;
        int right2 = current * 2 + 1;

        leftElement = get(left2);
        rightElement = get(right2);

        value1 = comp.compare(element, leftElement);
        value2 = comp.compare(element, rightElement);
    }

    // You must provide

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is `E` parameterized as `E extends Comparable<E>`?  Why aren't you updating `value1` or `value2` in the loop?

Comment: BinaryHeap<E> extends ArrayList<E>. And correct me if i'm wrong but aren't value1 and value2 both getting updated at the end of the while loop?

Comment: @Makoto sorry, forgot to tag

Comment: No.  You're calling a new method which has its own instance values for `value1` and `value2`.  That's likely what's breaking you.  Also, I was talking about your generic type `E`.  It has to be `E extends Comparable<E>` (well, it *is*, I suppose, or your code wouldn't compile).

Comment: I can't say that i am following what you are saying. What would i have to change in order to change that values of 1 & 2 versus comparing the element to its left and right children? @Makoto

Comment: Why are you bothering with the loop if you're recursing through the elements?  That's very strange to me.

Comment: through my understanding, I am replacing the root with the last value in the heap, and then deleting the last value. After that i find and compare the new root to its left and right children. if either of the values are greater than that of the root i enter the loop. I replace the root with the smaller child value, find the new children and repeat, exiting the loop once the "new root" is in order.

Comment: @Makoto forgot to tag again